# not null condition check

Tags: informix

In Informix:

how to check for not null,

I have a field with datetime data type, and I don't have any default values for this field, but I have lot of empty/null records for this field.

I want a query that will render the records:

```
(  cond like )  where  my_curr_date_time != ""
```

but if I try this query, it is not working.  Please tell which query for finding not null records.

Answer (score 2):

```
... WHERE my_curr_date_time IS NOT NULL
```

`NULL` is a special value. It may mean "no value" or "value unknown". In SQL if you want to check if value is or not is `NULL` then you must use ... yes ... `value IS NULL` or `value IS NOT NULL`. It may be used with other conditions like:

```
... WHERE my_curr_date_time IS NOT NULL AND my_curr_date_time > start_dt
```

Comment: Except that the DATETIME type is peculiar to Informix, this answer applies to most variants of SQL and most data types.